# What is the meaning of "if" in "If aspirins can cure it, I'll take a couple tonight."?

Tags: conditional-constructions

what means "if" in Zero conditional sentence "If aspirins will cure it, I'll take a couple tonight"? can we replace "if" with "because" or "since" in the sentence?

Comment: No. **if** <> **because**.  Consider.  "I was walking in the woods and now have a rash from poison-ivy. If aspirin will cure it, I will take a couple tonight".   Aspirin won't cure it. The speaker wonders about the possibility that aspirin might cure it.  On the condition that aspirin would cure it, the speaker would take a couple aspirin.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: If there's one thing I'm sure of, it's that when people say those first nine words they *always* intend them to be understood as meaning the speaker is 100% certain that the statement which follows is true.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: First nine words? Are you thinking of *If music be the food of love, play on*?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I certainly *used* to often be thinking of those nine words! Until I discovered password management / auto-generation software, I often had *Give me excess of it - or at least nine words to get me started* as my "password hint" for what I thought of as the relatively unguessable/secure password IMBTFOLPO. With a nod to Lewis Carroll, my other hardy perennial was TBATSTDGAGITW.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Now you'd need to mix case, use least one number and a special character (though not one of the forbidden special characters). WSw3MA?!

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: When indeed? If I'd thought about it when I was five (back in the 50s, when I doubt *any* computer systems were password-protected) I would have realised that the only password I knew at that time *(Open Sesame!)* was pretty useless in an environment where everyone knew it (or if they didn't, they could just copy Ali Baba and hang around the cave until the forty thieves turned up again). I really do think the net effect of Internet passwords today is to actually *reduce* security, not enhance it. My online / telephone bank now uses voice recognition, which seems much better to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although in my comment above I flatly rejected the notion that **if** means **because**, I do think it possible, in certain contexts, to understand **if** as "Since they say..." or "Since you say" or "Since it is said" or "Let's assume it's true".

That doesn't rise to equating **if** with **because**, but it does show a willingness on the part of the speaker to go along with an idea, to grant that something *may be true*.

> I have such a hangover from the New Years party!
>   — Here, have some whisky. You know what they say, "Hair of the dog".
>   If whisky will cure this headache, sure, I'll have some.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting "because" or "since" would alter the meaning.

The word "because" contains the word "cause" and identifies a cause. The information that aspirin cures what he is suffering from does not cause the speaker to take aspirin, instead he may choose to take aspirin. So saying "because" is a poor representation of the decision-making process.

The word "since" means "starting from". Used here metaphorically, it means that the speaker starts with a fact (aspirin cures his malady) and procedes to action (taking aspirin). This implies that he accepts the ability of aspirin to cure his malady as a fact.

Instead the speaker has used "if" because he does not yet fully accept that aspirin is a cure for his malady. He is saying what his course of action will be if he becomes convinced.